# Мета тег срабатывает не в том месте, где задан

Tags: css

Задан диапазон для медиа-запроса. `@media screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 1200px).` Меняет стиль с 1075 пикселя, а не с 1200. Подскажите пожалуйста что не так.

Comment: Дайте пример и как вы определяете пиксели

Comment: может у вас конфликт стилей?

Comment: @andreymal В другом проекте новые стили прописанные в медиазапросе применяются четко(на разных устройствах отображался корректно) в заданном диапазоне.

Comment: @soledar1 может и такое. К элементу применены стили и новые стили с медиазапроса вот и все

Comment: @Mizantrop без кода невозможно вам помочь